# Best solution to synchronize 2 databases with .NetCore 2

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I want to synchronise data from several tables from one database **DB1** to my .NetCore app's database **DB2** everyday.

I'm new to .Net Core. I have some skills with Java EE apps and Spring framework.

### First Try :-)

My first idea was to do that with SOAP WebServices so I create a WCF projet in my solution following this example : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=plRPBT3h3S8

#### Solution's content (in Visual Studio) :

- **Project 1 :** Web app in .NET Core 2.1 (*MVC architecture*)
- **Project 2 :** Dao project linked with **Projet 1** in .NET Core 2.0
- **Project 3 :** WCF project to expose SOAP web services with a ASMX file in .NET Framework 4.6.1

#### Problems :

- Imcompatibility beetwen .NET Framework 4.6.1 and .NET Core 2.1 when I tried to inject a service from **project 1** in the ASMX file from the **project 3**.
- There is a dependency beetween **project 1** and **project 3** to avoid duplicate the code beetween both project (setting  of dbcontext, services for instance) but I didn't succeed to make it works.

### Second try :-)

My second idea was to do link the *Service.svc* (in WCF **project 3**) to **project 1** with the WCF Web Service Reference Provider following this example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide

#### Problems :

- My *Service.svc* can't be found when I click on the "discover" button so I can't connect it with my **project 1**

#### Questions

1. Is one of these ideas are good to synchronize my database ?
2. I heard about "Service Fabric". Could it be another solution to solve it ?
3. Do you know other proper way to solve it with .NET Core ?

Thanks.

Comment: Its one time operation or you want to do it on regular basis?

Comment: This is a daily operation.

Comment: I Assume we are talking about Sql Server ?

Comment: Yes both databases are hosted on sql-server. They are hosted on differents phisical servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this situation using an API REST following this tutorial :

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

And I have developed a console application that request this API (post request with an HttpClient) to update my Application's database.

This program will be called by a planned task (CRON) to synchronise database everyday.

Comment: How did you go about doing the actual database sync? As in how did you manage what data needed to be transferred from DB1 to DB2 and vice versa?

Answer (score 3):

Please, review following .NET project (open source) that allows synchronize databases using .NET with C#.

[image: .NET Framework for syncing relational databases using C#]

Please, visit [Dotmin.Sync](https://dotmimsync.readthedocs.io/) for more info.

Easy code to perform a synchronization task:

```
 // Sql Server provider, the "server" or "hub".
SqlSyncProvider serverProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(
    @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=true;");

// Sqlite Client provider acting as the "client"
SqliteSyncProvider clientProvider = new SqliteSyncProvider("advworks.db");

// Tables involved in the sync process:
var tables = new string[] {"ProductCategory", "ProductDescription", "ProductModel", "Product", "ProductModelProductDescription",
                           "Address", "Customer", "CustomerAddress", "SalesOrderHeader", "SalesOrderDetail" };

// Sync agent
SyncAgent agent = new SyncAgent(clientProvider, serverProvider, tables);

do
{
    var result = await agent.SynchronizeAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(result);

} while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you to share this. I will have a look the next time I will have a similar need. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well I dont see any best solution it really depends. But there are some options.

You dont need to load any of your old .net framework code in .net core for db sync, all you 
need to do connect from .net core to database to load data. Yes you could have code duplication but at least your solution will be in .net core where you control whole process. In addition If you would use EF be careful how you load data and manipulate memory.

Second option which I would use is [SSDT project](http://%20http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2013/01/multiple-configurations-in-ssdt.html). You will write data transformation process loading from any source you wish, I assume it even supports text files. Also it can connect to different database providers so you can load from MySql for instance and write to SqlServer (In one of my projects I've done Postgres to mssql). Benefit of this solution that you can do easily different flows error handling.

And last one could be simple stored procedure if you have databases on same server you could create new user which will have read access to DB1 and read/write to DB2, then using insert/from or update/from statements.

Here is no silver bullet so you need to try your self because there is many factors.

Comment: There are many tools and languages that could be used for accomplishing this task. NodeJS, Java, C#, Python, SQL in the database itself using batch processing and lots of slight variations in  your cloud of choice if that's where you are running. It would be pretty easy in any of these. The best choice is probably the tools an languages you are using for the rest of the project. Adding additional tools is entertaining for the developer, but tends to make things harder to support as time goes on.

Comment: @GlennSills this is why it depends :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the design of the databases will have a much greater impact on the difficulty of this effort than anything else. If it is easy to identify rows in Db1 that aren't in DB2 and visa versa the code is trivial. I wouldn't bother with a multi-tiered application - keep things as simple as possible. Just write a console application. Later on you can schedule it with the task manager on Windows Server, or cron on Linux.

Comment: There is no important transformation on the data beetween the both databases so maybe it could be the simplest solution. I'll see and let you know what we've done.

Comment: I should have mentioned that if you want to deploy to Azure or AWS the same code can be deployed to Webjobs, Lambdas or Serverless functions with minor or no modification.

Answer (score 0):

I use this library which synchronizes multiple databases.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/SyncData_dotNET/

```
    // Tables involved in the sync process:
    var tables = new string[] { "anagrafica" };

    string clientConnectionString = @"Data Source=" + server + "; Database=" + database + "; User ID=" + username + "; Password=" + password + ";";
    string serverConnectionString = @"Data Source=" + server + "; Database=" + database + "; User ID=" + username + "; Password=" + password + ";";

    // Sqlite Client provider for a MySql <=> Sqlite sync
    SQLiteConnection clientProvider = new SQLiteConnection(clientConnectionString);

    // MySql Server provider, the master.
    MySqlConnection serverProvider = new MySqlConnection(serverConnectionString);

    // Launch the sync process
    var result = await Sync.Synchronize(clientProvider, serverProvider, tables);
```

Comment: The original question is for .NET Core 2,  Your solution does not use .NET Core, it use .NET Framework 3.5, 4, 4.5, 4.6 & 4.7.